# Query no devuelve datos correctos

Tags: sql, date

Tengo este query que debería devolver los datos que están entre los rangos de fecha solicitados.

```
SELECT i.description_item,it.quantityTicket,it.price_Ticket,i.reorder_level,i.target_Stock,
            it.comentTicket,it.registerTicket ,l.name_location,u.name_unit,s.company_supplier,i.status,c.name_category,i.folio
            FROM inventory_ticket AS it
            INNER JOIN inventory_list AS i ON numFile = fk_Inventory
            INNER JOIN category as c on id_category = fk_Inventory
            INNER JOIN location as l on id_location = fk_Inventory
            INNER JOIN unit_mesurement as u on id_unit = fk_Inventory
            INNER JOIN supplier as s on id_supplier = numFile
            WHERE it.registerTicket BETWEEN '2019-02-06' AND '2019-02-08' AND i.status = 1
```

Tengo varios datos econ fecha de `2019-02-07` y  que su status es `1` es decir esta dentro del rango, pero aun así no me los muestra.

Por que estará ocurriendo eso?

Comment: Hace una prueba, si el campo es datetime en fecha de inicio pone la fecha mas 00:00:01 y en fecha de fin pone 23:59:59

Comment: Revisa tus inner join, tal vez en alguno de esos están quedando fuera los datos que indicas. Prueba con left join o right join

Comment: Si lo pones así debería funcionar: `WHERE DATE(it.registerTicket) BETWEEN '2019-02-06' AND '2019-02-08'`   puede que estés teniendo problemas con la parte del tiempo. `DATE` tomará sólo la fecha, ignorando el tiempo. Si aún así no funciona, entonces es por lo que comenta @antonio_veneroso